# jQuery mask plugin currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

For my project I'm using [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). On the site of this plugin there is an example for currency / money.

```
$('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
$('.money2').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true, maxlength: false});
```

This is not exactly what I'm after, because I want the `,00` be optional in the mask.
Can this be done?

Assertions:

```
input   | output
________|___________
1111    | 1.111
2222222 | 2.222.222
12,34   | 12,34
1234,56 | 1.234,56
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/884kN/1/)

Comment: I had a quick look to your problem but the plugin is not currently allowing such a functionality (even with "optional" use)

Comment: @NicolasR I was afraid of this. Thank you for your observation.

Comment: I also looked at other plugins (like maskMoney), same problem